# know when the RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager populates the next row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, gridlayoutmanager

How can i know when a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager is done with the first row and about to populate the next row items? I am trying to give different span values to the items of my RecyclerView.